# Difference between AngularJS(1.x) and Angular (2/4) Decorator

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-decorators

I am getting started with Angular version 2 and came across @Component Decorator. I could recall that AngularJS(1.x) also had a concept of Decorator where it was used extend/change the default implementation of any service.

It seems like in Angular 2, rather than changing/extending the default functionality, they add metadata to something ranging from Class(using @Component) to a property(using Input()/Output() decorators) and the list goes on for Pipes and services etc.

Could someone provide the differences, if any, between the two in terms of
concept/actual working.

Thanks.
Deepak

Comment: https://toddmotto.com/angular-decorators

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/Component#description

Comment: Except for the name, there is basically nothing common. AngularJS decorators are a rarely used feature allowing to wrap/proxy an existing service. TypeScript decorators allow annotating various parts of the code to provide metadata, and they're used everywhere in Angular to define components, services, pipes, modules, etc. Don't try to see one as the same thing as the other.

Comment: @JBNizet - I get your point. But I think Angular 2 Decorators are a ES 2015 feature rather than a TypeScript feature, is it true?

Comment: No. Decorators don't exist in ES (yet).

Comment: Thanks :)

And thanks to everyone above for pointing me to relevant urls , appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

#### AngularJS

AngularJS decorator is an [OOP pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

It is rarely used in AngularJS to extend behavior of the built-in objects. For example, the following [implementation](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/10/07/enhance-angularjs-logging-using-decorators/) uses `$provider.decorator()` to intercept `$log.debug()` calls and dynamically prepend timestamp information.

```
$provide.decorator('$log', [
    "$delegate", function ($delegate) {
        // Save the original $log.debug()
        var debugFn = $delegate.debug;

        $delegate.debug = function () {
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments),
                now = DateTime.formattedNow();

            // Prepend timestamp
            args[0] = supplant("{0} - {1}", [now, args[0]]);

            // Call the original with the output prepended with formatted timestamp
            debugFn.apply(null, args)
        };

        return $delegate;
    }
]);
```

#### Angular

Angular decorators is [a language-feature](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/) that:

> offers a convenient declarative syntax to modify the shape of class
>   declarations. This capability can be used for myriad purposes
>   including modifying the descriptor of the declared member
>   (@nonconfigurable/@enumerable), adding metadata (as used by Angular),
>   and more. It allows attaching accessing

Angular uses it to attach metadata to a class, class member (property) and method parameters. To see how Angular does this read [Implementing custom component decorator in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular-4d037d5a3f0d).

In the versions greater than 4 Angular will be moving away from dynamic evaluation of decorators during runtime and will be using static code analysis to extract metadata specified in the decorator descriptors.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. But as stated in official AngularJS documentation :

What are decorators?
Decorators are a design pattern that is used to separate modification or decoration of a class without modifying the original source code. In AngularJS, decorators are functions that allow a service, directive or filter to be modified prior to its usage.




May be I used wrong verb: "extend", rather it should be change/modify the existing behavior of a service. Like you did in your example above, where you have modified the existing behavior of $log service to prepend a timestamp now.

Comment: @DeepakPathak, you're welcome, didn't quite understand your question if there's any :)